# start activity by adapter's item position

Tags: android

don't know whether the title matches the context or not but here is what i'm trying to do : I have two buttons on **MainActivity** when user click button1 it starts the **Home** activity which contains list of all apps installed, now if the user selects any app from list like browser it should return to MainActivity. And now when user click button2 it should open the app(browser) which was selected earlier from list on Home activity.

Even little help will be much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

MainActivity:

```
final int APPLIST = 10;
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1:
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.DRAWER");
        startActivityForResult(i,APPLIST);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
                            // starts an app(selected earlier)
        break;
    }

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == APPLIST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // don't know what to get (may be app item position)
     }
    }
}
```

Home activity:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
// for starting selected app    
// ApplicationInfo app = (ApplicationInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
// startActivity(app.intent);       

//instead of starting app from here, I want to put data in extra something like that & returns with data back to MainActivity
```

ApplicationInfo:

```
class ApplicationInfo {

CharSequence title;
Intent intent;
Drawable icon;
boolean filtered;

final void setActivity(ComponentName className, int launchFlags) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(className);
    intent.setFlags(launchFlags);
}
}
```

Comment: Call `setResult()` in `onClick()`, then `finish()`. Furthermore you must make ApplicationInfo serializable or parcelable to transfer its data in an intent.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply Michael, & sorry i don't understand cuz i'm a newbie. Would you give an example or some link. Thanks

Comment: You should read in the Android documentation about the class `Activity` and especially about its functions `setResult()` and `finish()`. For information about serialization you can start at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Comment: is this what you were refering on ItemClick on Home activity                             Intent a = new Intent();
a.putExtra("data", what should i write here app item postion or something else);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, a);
finish();           and as for serialization i'll read your link.

Comment: When you have the `ApplicationInfo` in `app` you can put it as extra in the intent: `a.putExtra("data", app)` (after you made it serializable)

Comment: I read about serialization but didn't understand, how to exactly implement the code in my ApplicationInfo activity. Can you write few lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what the activity does which you want to start, different things must be transferred to it. A `Drawable` can't be serialized so some information about how it was created must be transferred instead (or reconstructed in the target application). An `Intent` is hard to serialize but it is parcelable, so maybe it should be packed into another extra of the intent you want to send to other activity or only the component information and the launchFlags should be serialized. There are too many variations. You should narrow it down and ask new questions